# не работает video html5 на Android. прошу помощи?

Tags: android, html5, видео

У меня отказывается грузится `video html5` на Android,
видео ролик в формате `mp4 "h.264" "ACC"`.
Не хотелось бы использовать сторонние видео плееры на сайте,
У кого был опыт решения данной проблемы?
В общем нужны скрипты для запуска.

Comment: Через что ты запускаешь, через браузер или собственное приложение c WebView? Одна из возможных проблем - это установлен autoplay в таге <video>.

Comment: видео запускаю через браузер. не использую приложений. autoplay отсутсвует

Comment: Покажи код страницы и версию андроид.

Comment: <video width="854" height="510" controls="controls" poster="....jpg"  id="myVideo">
<source src="...mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>